# Countifs where using 2 criteria on different column Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, count, sum, vlookup, countif

I've a table on excel as bellow :

[image]

The problem I am facing now is that I want to calculate the amount of data with the following conditions:

Scene 1:
1. Mikaela purchases DEV01 (can be DEV02 or DEV03) which has the MDN serial number: 88217094212
2. If Mikaela performs a top up PUL100 (can bePUL60 or PUL50) on the MDN serial number: 88217094212
3. Then the condition will be calculated 1

Scene:
1. John made a purchase of DEV01 (can be DEV02 or DEV03) which has the MDN serial number: 88900253676
2. If John doesn't top up PUL100 (can be PUL60 or PUL50) on the MDN serial number: 88900253676
3. Then the condition is not counted

In the table below the following data are eligible as above have been marked yellow block calculated as 1 count, if calculated as a whole then the number should appear = 3

I've tried by doing the following calculations:

= COUNTIFS (B2: B10, "DEV01")

From the results of these calculations I am still confused how to reference data calculation by using several criteria on different columns. Thanks for your help and cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another formula:

```
=SUM((--(A2:A9&LEFT(B2:B9,3)=A2:A9&"DEV")*(--(A3:A10&LEFT(B3:B10,3)=A3:A10&"PUL"))*(--(D3:D10<>""))))
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
Choose A2:A9 the Name column less 1 row from down (each Dev is above Pul to be counted)
B2:B9 column of DEV and PUL to make for example "MikaelaDEV" using `left(B2:B9,3)`
if `=A2:A9&"DEV"` it will evaluate to 1
the same for "PUL"
Choose 1 row less from up `A3:A10` till the last row
it will evaluate to 1 when `=A3:A10&"PUL"`
`D3:D10 <>""` evaluate to 1 if not empty
The product 1*1*1=1
Sum will add the 1 when the three conditions evaluate to 1

With Countifs you have to write:

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A3:A10,B2:B9,"DEV*",B3:B10,"PUL*",D3:D10,"<>""")`

And change the references to your Data
Always make a difference of one row but the count of rows have to be the same

Comment: Because i'm not as smart as you,.... so i took the simple formula =COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A3:A10,B2:B9,"DEV*",B3:B10,"PUL*",D3:D10,"<>""") ,..... but after i execute that formula, it generate 0 value, whats wrong with my excel ??? would you help me ???